# execute jquery every 5 seconds withing a change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having a chart which will be updated every 5 seconds to show the how many users have entered a building and the user has an option to select how many users are on each floor. this is also updated every 5 seconds

below is my code to get the users entered the building

```
var interval = 5000; 
function get_Users() {
     var users=   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php')?>/building/feed',
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            success: function (users) {
                 $('.current').html(users); 

            },
            complete: function (users){

                    setTimeout(get_Users, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(doFeed, interval);
```

below is used to get the users on each floor

```
$(document).on('change','.floor',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'floor/chart',
        type: 'post',
        data: asset,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (users) {

             $(".current").html(users.floor);
        },


    });
});
```

what i need to do is once its successfully changed, post and get the chart values every 5 seconds..

how can this be done? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think both  the scripts are running in the same page, are they ?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: _doFeed_ is it the correct one call in the setTimeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by create a named function for `change` handler and trigger a `timeout` function once the first one complete as you have done it for other function in your code.

```
$(document).on('change','.floor',changeFloorHandler);

 function changeFloorHandler() {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'floor/chart',
    type: 'post',
    data: asset,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (users) {
         $(".current").html(users.floor);
    },
    complete: function (users){
        setTimeout(changeFloorHandler, interval);
    }
  });
 }
```

*Note: I would suggest you to have a common `ajax` function in your code with custom parameters holding `callback` functions reference for `timeout` instead of multiple function definitions to avoid redundant code.*